# How to get the uneven keys from an array?

Tags: php

I have to create a function that copy the array(that i pass to the function) with only uneven keys. Example:

```
$a = array(
  '0'   => '0',
  'one  => 'one',
  '1'   => '1',
  'two' => 'two'
)
```

I have to get:

```
$result = array(
  'one  => 'one',
  'two' => 'two'
)
```

I have created the follow function, it works, but maybe I need to optimize it(maybe exists a function that does this job). Advice?

```
private clean($values){
    $vv   = array();            
    $keys = array_keys($values);        

    for($i=1; $i < count($values); $i+=2) $vv[$keys[$i]] = $values[$keys[$i]];              
    return $vv;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "uneven" keys? Do you mean every other key? What happens if your array is array('0'   => '0',
  'one  => 'one',
  'two' => 'two',
  '1'   => '1'
)

Comment: @liquorvicar, it is not important i have to get key=>value of the array with those indexes: 1 - 3 - 5 - 7 etc etc

Comment: But the indexes you pull out in your example are 'one' and 'two'. Do you want the key/value pairs in those positions in the array? btw if this is a homework question please tag as such.

Comment: @liquorvicar, I need key=>value in those positions: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 etc etc

Comment: See my answer below. I think that will give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
$even = range(0, count($array), 2);
```

[*source*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

**UPDATE**:

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($array); $i <= $c; $i = $i + 2) {
    $even = array_push($even, $array[$i]);
}
```

Comment: @ZoltanToth, thank you! Only a small error: range(1, count($array), 2);

Comment: No wait, one moment...it only return an array with 1 3 5 7 etc etc, I need the respective key=>value of the original array. Not only those numbers

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$outputArray = array();
$keyToAdd = false;
foreach( $inputArray as $key => $value ) {
    if( $keyToAdd ) {
        $outputArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    $keyToAdd = !$keyToAdd;
}
```